# Extracting particular field from Nsstring

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I want to extract value of a particular field from NSString which i think is a Json string.

what i am trying to do is

```
NSString *picurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"picture"]];
```

After this instruction i am getting picurl as

```
{
    data =     {
        "is_silhouette" = 1;
        url = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-1/c15.0.50.50/p50x50/10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg?oh=0d6173b2f424d27585b00d7b7190a10c&oe=55AB362F&__gda__=1437591769_4adb584761f22e225809b0a8f10ffbca";
    };
}
```

From above i want to extract url.How can i do so. I am not having any idea about Json.

Comment: it kind of looks like the picurl is in fact an NSDictionary object?

Comment: Better to find out what type the object returned is and access it directly.

Comment: Hi first you can add the [result objectForKey:@"picture"] to NSDictionary.From dictionary you can get the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would mean it is a dictionary object so;

```
NSDictionary *pictureData = [result objectForKey:@"picture"];
NSDictionary *data = [pictureData objectForKey:@"data"];
NSString *picurl = [data objectForKey:@"url"];
```

Answer (score 1):

First convert NSString to NSData using dataUsingEncoding: method like this :

```
NSData *data = [[result objectForKey:@"picture"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

then use the JSONObjectWithData method and add it to array :

```
NSArray *responseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
```

if your string is in dictionary format then use this :

```
NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil]lastObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

One line answer :

```
NSString *picurl = result[@"picture"][@"data"][@"url"];
```

Answer (score 0):

ACCORDING TO ME INSTEAD OF WRITING THIS TYPE OF CODE LIKE:

```
self.name = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *picurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"picture"]];
```

You can use JSONModel

- JSONModel is a data model framework for iOS
  Just declare properties in your model with the same names as the keys in your JSON and voila! The heavy work is done automatically for you.

So, just declare your properties like usual in your interface file:

```
@interface MyModel: JSONModel
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* id;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* name;
(etc...)
@end
```

JSONModel's inherited initWithDictionary: method will take care to match incoming JSON keys with your model's properties, and copy over the matching ones. No need of any code in your implementation file.
[You should take a moment to star and start watching JSONModel on GitHub:](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel/)